# Is this ethical and what recourse do I have?

Tags: ethics

My nursing instructor thought I was taking drugs while at clinical within ear shot of patient I just helped. Teacher made a comment about me shooting up drugs. She also caused embarrassment by throwing up her arms after asking me to take a drug screen and made comments where staff and other students could easily hear.

I was not on any drugs. Another teacher lied for this teacher when I had meeting regarding first teacher. The teacher who lied gave me a passing grade on a procedure, said I did very well. There is documentation that teacher passed me on procedure. She never said anything to anybody about me being under the influence. She allowed me to work with sharp objects and then drive.

Several days later, the day of the meeting regarding the first teacher, this teacher wrote a letter saying I was not capable of performing simple math, slurring my speech, and being high. How can she get away with this obvious lie? The letter she wrote was about my open lab performance--which she gave me a passing grade for.

Comment: It might help answers to know which country your course is located, as regulations are location specific. If this is the UK the Nursing Instructors have definitely strayed outside the NMC guidelines that govern their own license to practise, for example.

Comment: This probably will fall under defamation (among other things) which is illegal in US.

Comment: You need to work this out with your university. Only there is there any chance of verifying your statements and the statements of others. There is no way to find truth at this distance with this information and therefore no way to help you.

Comment: Might be better addressed in the WorkPlace SE even though you are a nursing student.